# Method for key-value pair similar to explode in php?

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

Is there an already existing function in PHP for creating an associative array from a delimited string? If not, what would be the most effective means of doing so? I am looking at PayPal's new NVP API, where requests and responses have the following format:

```
 method=blah&name=joe&id=joeuser&age=33&stuff=junk
```

I can use `explode()` to get each pair into an array value, but it would be even better if I could do some sort of function like `dictionary_explode` and indicate the key-value delimiter and get back an associate array like:

```
Array {
 [method] => blah
 [name] => joe
 [id] => joeuser
 [age] => 33
 [stuff] => junk
```

}

My CS friends tell me that this idea exists in other languages like Python, so I'm wondering if I just haven't found such a thing for PHP. Right now I'm looking at doing an array_walk, but I'd prefer something more pre-built.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP has an inbuilt function for it: [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

> ```
> <?php
> $str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
> parse_str($str);
> echo $first;  // value
> echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
> echo $arr[1]; // baz
>
> parse_str($str, $output);
> echo $output['first'];  // value
> echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
> echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
>
> ?>
> ```

**Note:** My recommendation is to *not* use the first form (`parse_str($str)`) for the same reason `register_globals` is bad. The second form (`parse_str($str, $arr)`) is always preferred.

Comment: +1 I was so happy when I came across that function a few weeks back. The second function keeps a crafted querystring from overwriting global variables with the same name.

Comment: I was really wanting something where the tokens could be defined (and thus not limited to the x=y&a=b model, but I could actually make a function that passes the tokens I want and then does a string replace and then parse_str and returns the array, so this is pretty dang close to what I had in mind. Thanks!